# ّFrechet differentiable norms implies LUR norms?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space with a Frechet differentiable norm. Does $X$ admit an equivalent LUR norm?

Answer (score 0):

This is stated as an open problem in the 2002 survey [Banach spaces of continuous functions on compact spaces](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1969998) by  Godefroy.

[image: Godefroy]

In the more recent survey [Smoothness in Banach spaces. Selected problems](http://www.rac.es/ficheros/doc/00218.pdf) by Fabian,  Montesinos and Zizler (page 119) the weaker form of this problem is stated (also open): "Assume that $X$ admits a $C^\infty$ smooth norm. Does $X$ admit an LUR norm?".

Among the most recent papers on the subject, a relevant one is [$C^k$-smooth approximations of LUR norms](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2014-366-04/S0002-9947-2013-05899-0/home.html) by Hájek and Procházka, but it addresses a different aspect of the LUR renorming problem.